# How do I remove time from Pandas df column when it isn't in the excel column?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have read in two worksheets separately into pandas dataframes. Both have date issued columns.

In both worksheets the column is held in excel as dd/mm/yyyy.

ws1

```
13/02/2017
01/02/2017
08/11/2016
05/08/2016
16/03/2017

53   2017-02-13
51   2017-02-01
22   2016-11-08
0    2016-08-05
63   2017-03-16
Name: Date Issued, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But ws2

```
08/03/2017
24/08/2016
28/11/2016
26/10/2016
10/03/2017


0    2017-03-08 00:00:00
1    2016-08-24 00:00:00
2    2016-11-28 00:00:00
3    2016-10-26 00:00:00
4    2017-03-10 00:00:00
Name: Date Issued, dtype: object
```

Why is it that the dtypes are different and how can I apply remove the time?

The code currently looks like nothing out the ordinary for dealing with pandas

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, 'ws2')
df = df.loc[:, ['Date Issued', 'Person ID',
                          'First Name', 'Surname', 'Type',  'Amount']]
df = df.sort_values(by=['Surname'])
df['Date Issued'] = pd.to_datetime(df_loan['Date Issued'], dayfirst=True)
```

I have tried to use;

```
df['Date Issued'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Issued'], dayfirst=True)
```

But get the following error;

```
TypeError: invalid string coercion to datetime
```

Also;

```
df['Date Issued'] = df['Date Issued'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

But getting this error;

```
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string " " at position 1
```

Comment: What happens in your pd.to_datetime() when you set infer_datetime_format=True ?

Comment: I still get the same TypeError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is at least one non datetime value.

So need parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert these values to `NaT` (`NaN` for datetimes) in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Date Issued'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Issued'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Fantastic. I did see this parameter but didn't think that it would solve everything. Seems that there is a rogue blank link being read in from excel that caused the whole error. But I hadn't notice only dealing with the .head() when reviewing the data.

Live and learn. Again Jezrael you have been amazing!